# Initialize php object with arguments, while its constructor doesn't take any (singleton pattern)

Tags: php, object, singleton, instance

I have only basic PHP knowledge and am reading the book "PHP 5 E-commerce Development.pdf" which code source can be found here: https://github.com/rogeriorps/books_demo.

I am right at the beginning, on the creation of the registry with "objects" such as database handling, authentication and template sending.

I have a problem with the last line of code of this function, in a class that is a singleton and has objects:

```
public function storeObject( $object, $key )
{

    if( strpos( $object, 'database' ) !== false ) {
         $object = str_replace( '.database', 'database', $object);
         require_once('databaseobjects/' . $object
         . '.database.class.php');
   } else {
     require_once('objects/' . $object . '.class.php');
   }
   self::$objects[ $key ] = new $object( self::$instance );

}
```

Well, for the authentication class for instance, the constructor is empty: public

```
function __construct() { }
```

So it would require authentication.class.php and then create a new authentification(self::$instance)... On a constructor has no arguments!

How is that possible? What bothers me is the use of the word **new**, which normally calls the empty constructor, and gives it arguments out of the blue.

Any further explanations about how this all works are welcome as well, thank you :-)

Comment: Didn't I just answer this the other day?

Comment: I'm sorry, your answers were assuming the objects were singletons too and I couldn't quite communicate the question to you. Thank you for your effort anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a quite forgiving language, in that certain language constructs and practices are not as strictly applied as in other programming languages.

PHP does not complain if you provide *more* parameters than a class method expects, whether that method is a costructor or regular method. See below, which outputs "Hello World!" just fine:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);

class Foo
{
    public function __construct() {}
    public function hello($input) { return 'Hello ' . $input . '!'; }
}

$foo = new Foo(123);
echo $foo->hello('World', 'Universe');
```

Comment: Ooh, thank you very much that's very interesting to know, but then is there any use to passing the class instance to the objects?

Comment: That will have no effect, positive or negative. It looks like the code you posted is some sort of container object, where it assumes that the objects it contains require itself as a passed argument in the constructor. As a personal opinion, I'd consider that a very odd design pattern, but I don't know the context from which this code is written or what the author was intending.

Comment: alright thank you, I linked the source code just in case, but I'm going to try and dabble with it when I have the time to see what they meant :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to understand what your question is.

While the link to the source code is good, can you be more specific as to what files you are talking about.

Is this the line you are referring too? :

```
  //I will call this class 'Singleton',as I have no idea what it's name is.
 class Singleton
 {

  protected static $instance;

  protected static $objects = [];
  ...
  public function storeObject( $object, $key )
  {
       ...
       self::$objects[ $key ] = new $object( self::$instance ); //<--- this line
       ...
  }
}
```

And then you say you have a class like this ( with an empty constructor )

```
class authenticate{  
    public function __construct() {} //empty
}
```

IF I follow that right, the extra argument is ignored in this case.  However, consider having another class that can be stored in `Singleton`

```
class user{  
    //instance of singleton
    protected $singleton;

    public function __construct( $Singleton ) {
        $this->singleton = $Singleton;
    } 
}
```

So in this case the same class `Singlton` calls a different class that does accept an instance of `Singlton`.

This is what I would call a form of Polymorphism.

> Polymorphism is the provision of a single interface to entities of different types.

Personally I would prefer they actually have an interface for this.  I will try to explain this as best I can.  An interface can be thought of like a contract, it guarantees that any class implementing it will expose some public methods, with given arguments, in a specific order.

For example this

```
  interface StorableObjectInterface{

      //interfaces do not contain a method body, only the definition
      //here I am using type hinting to tell it to only accept instance of Singleton
      public function __construct( Singleton $Singleton );

  }
```

So what this does is require that every class that implements this interface requires an instance of singleton as it's constructors first argument.  They can still ignore it, but it should be a contractual obligation of being called from `Singleton` (IMO).

Then your clasess would look like this

```
class authenticate implements StorableObjectInterface{  
    public function __construct(Singleton $Singleton) {} // still empty
}

class user implements StorableObjectInterface{  
    //instance of singlton
    protected $singlton;

    public function __construct(Singleton $Singleton ) {
        $this->singlton = $Singleton;
    } 
}
```

And then to lock it all together in Singleton you would check that `$Object` implements the interface.

```
  public function storeObject( $object, $key )
  {
       ...
       if( is_a( $object, StorableObjectInterface::class ){
           self::$objects[ $key ] = new $object( self::$instance );
       }else{
            //throw exception
           throw new Exception("Class {$object} must implement interface ".StorableObjectInterface::class); 
        }
       ...
  }
```

This is the way I would do it...  It wasn't clear if you are just Using someones system, or creating your own.

So you may wonder why go through all this trouble, I'll give you an example.

Say later on you may need something like a path to a config file in `authenticate`, so you can easily load you credentials etc.

So you look in that class and see this ( we'll forget we know what we know )

```
class authenticate{  
    public function __construct() {} // still empty
}
```

So you figure you can just tack it in the constructor ( say you were using this class somewhere outside of Singlton ).  So you change it.

```
class authenticate{ 
    protected $config; 
    public function __construct($configFile = null) {
        if( $configFile )
            $this->config = include $configFile;
    }
}

//then you call it for you new code

$z = new authenticate('passwordsAndStuf.php');
```

This is all fine until `Singleton` calls that constructor with an instance of itself.  Now everything blows up.  The main issue is that just looking at `authenticate` there is no way to tell this is going to happen.  So by adding an Interface we are making a contract with `Singleton any class implementing this interface will always accept an instance of`Singleton` as the first argument.

Hope that makes sense.